# how to call my api qnamaker using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Knowledge.QnAMaker nuget version 1.0.0

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I am getting started with Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Knowledge.QnAMaker nuget,
and  I am trying to use  QnAMakerClient() class to initialise a new instance of the QNAMakerClient class.

But  this class takes abstract parameters : 
public QnAMakerClient(ServiceClientCredentials credentials, params DelegatingHandler[] handlers).
 I found some solution 
https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Microsoft.Rest/TokenCredentials/-/php-tokencredentials-class-examples.html which indicates how to get the credentials token.

As I am new to this concept, so I don't know how to get credentials token for my ServiceClientCredentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own **TokenCredentials** class which inherit from **ServiceClientCredentials** as shown below:

```
 public class TokenCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials
    {
         /// <summary>
        /// The bearer token type, as serialized in an http Authentication header.
        /// </summary>
        private const string BearerTokenType = "Bearer";

       /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets secure token used to authenticate against Microsoft Azure API. 
        /// No anonymous requests are allowed.
        /// </summary>
        protected ITokenProvider TokenProvider { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TokenCredentials"/>
        /// class with the given 'Bearer' token.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token">Valid JSON Web Token (JWT).</param>
        public TokenCredentials(string token)
            : this(token, BearerTokenType)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TokenCredentials"/>
        /// class with the given token and token type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token">Valid JSON Web Token (JWT).</param>
        /// <param name="tokenType">The token type of the given token.</param>
        public TokenCredentials(string token, string tokenType) 
            : this(new StringTokenProvider(token, tokenType))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("token");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("tokenType");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create an access token credentials object, given an interface to a token source.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tokenProvider">The source of tokens for these credentials.</param>
        public TokenCredentials(ITokenProvider tokenProvider)
        {
            if (tokenProvider == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("tokenProvider");
            }

            this.TokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply the credentials to the HTTP request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request">The HTTP request.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">Cancellation token.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Task that will complete when processing has completed.
        /// </returns>
        public async override Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
            }

            if (TokenProvider == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.TokenProviderCannotBeNull);
            }

            request.Headers.Authorization = await TokenProvider.GetAuthenticationHeaderAsync(cancellationToken);
            await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.knowledge.qnamaker?view=azure-dotnet) is a good starting point for knowing more about [QnAMaker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/overview/overview).

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I find another way to initialised my QnAMakerClient() ,

Comment: I find another way to initialised my QnAMakerClient() ,                                                            QnAMakerClient client = new QnAMakerClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("XXXXXX")) { Endpoint = "https://XXXXXX" };
   var kbData = await  client.Knowledgebase.DownloadWithHttpMessagesAsync("XXXXXX", "Prod");          But i have an exception that i can't resolve,

Comment: Can you please explain in detail and open a new issue on what exception you are encountering? Also, if the above answer was helpful, can you accept the answer so that it helps others?Thanks

Comment: finally, I did not use the right subscription key, and the solution you offered me works perfectly, except that I use the nuget  Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Knowledge.QnAMaker and i have the function that creat the Credentials, so the exception was not obvious but by analising the url, and trying to call my api qnamaker, from the portal qnqmaker.ai, I found that it was my subscription key, which was not the right one,